# Passing Value of Asynctask in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, fragment

I have been working with passing the result created by the `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask` in `Fragment`. 
I know how to do it in `Activity`, like `((MyActivity)context).someMethod();`
But how can I do this in `Fragment`?

I do `((MyFragment)contextOfAsyncTask).methodInFragment()` but it gives me an error "Cannot cast from Context to MyFragment".

Here is my code in AsyncTask

class AsyncMethod extends AsyncTask{

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myVar= new ArrayList<MyObject>();
String result;
ListView lv;
Context contextOfAsyncTask;


public AsyncMethod(Context xc, ListView xl){
    contextOfAsyncTask= xc;
    lv = xl;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void...param) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(http://www.myurl.com/something.php);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);      

    return null; //EVERYTHING IS WORKING FINE HERE, AND I CAN GET THE VALUE
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
             //it does not work here
    ((MyFragment)contextOfAsyncTask).methodInFragment(result);
}
```

Comment: Could you post your AsyncTask code?

Comment: @note-knotz what you want to return and where you want to return.?

Answer (score 0):

It is look like you want to call method from `AsyncTask`

```
class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  private SomeFragment fragment;

  YourTask(SomeFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
  {
    //do whatever you want to do
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
  {
     fragment.yourmethod();
  }
}
```

i hope it help..